# Mup deploy - js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version

Tags: meteor, deployment, meteor-up

Trying to deploy my meteorJS app to digital ocean droplet under Ubuntu 14.04 with the help of Meteor Up

`mup init` is sucessful but when I deploy I have:

```
 -----------------------------------STDERR-----------------------------------
    npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No description
    npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No repository field.
    npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No README data
    js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
      % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                     Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
    0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused
    Latest deployment failed! Reverted back to the previous version.
    -----------------------------------STDOUT-----------------------------------
    /ansi-styles

    chalk@0.5.1 node_modules/chalk

    escape-string-regexp@1.0.3 node_modules/escape-string-regexp

    strip-ansi@0.3.0 node_modules/strip-ansi

    has-ansi@0.1.0 node_modules/has-ansi

    supports-color@0.2.0 node_modules/supports-color

    eachline@2.3.3 node_modules/eachline

    type-of@2.0.1 node_modules/type-of

    amdefine@1.0.0 node_modules/amdefine

    asap@2.0.3 node_modules/asap

    underscore@1.5.2 node_modules/underscore

    meteor-promise@0.5.0 node_modules/meteor-promise

    promise@7.0.4 node_modules/promise

    source-map-support@0.3.2 node_modules/source-map-support

    semver@4.1.0 node_modules/semver

    source-map@0.1.32 node_modules/source-map

    fibers@1.0.5 node_modules/fibers
    Waiting for MongoDB to initialize. (5 minutes)
    { [Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
    connected
    admin stop/waiting
    admin start/running, process 14399
    Waiting for 30 seconds while app is booting up
    Checking is app booted or not?
    admin stop/waiting
    admin start/running, process 14542
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Config :

```
 node -v
 v0.10.40

npm list bson
└── bson@0.4.20
```

I've seen a lot of issue resolved by changing
`bson = require('../build/Release/bson');`
to
`bson = require('../browser_build/bson');`

But where do I find my node_module ? I have one directory at the root of my app but in this directory I don't even have `/build` only `browser_build` so I can"t try this fix ...